# OpenMP pyramidal nested loop counter

Tags: c, openmp

i want to use OpenMP to parallelize my code, but am unsure how my loop can keep its properties.

I know how many times the inner loop generates an result, and how big it is:

(depending on evenness of width, the inner loop behaves differently, thus the ceiling and flooring division)

```
const size_t
    bytes_per_result = <something>,
    totalloops = width/2 * iceildiv(width, 2);
```

So I can write each result into a known position inside the file. For this I just allocate a file of that size, and rewind it to the beginning:

```
FILE* f = fopen(<somefile>, "w");
fseek(f, totalloops * bytes_per_result - 1, SEEK_SET); //seek to before file end
fputc('\0', f); //write byte to allocate whole file
rewind(f);
```

And then I just loop, and count the number the inner loop is run via `k`. After the last loop, `k == totalloops`.

```
result_t result;
size_t i, j, k;
for (i=0, k=0; i<width; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<imin(i, width-i-1); j++, k++) {
        result = do_calculation(i, j);
        fseek(f, k * bytes_per_result, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite_result(f, result);
    }
}
```

Now how can I parallelize that? The thing to parallelize is of course the `do_calculation` part, while the seeking and writing must be declared `#pragma omp critical` together. But how can i make `k` behave like i want to?

OpenMP can only parse simple for loops with one increment expression at the end, not two, so i can’t keep `k++` there…

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in 2 steps:

1. calculate the result in parallel and store the result in RAM buffer
2. write the entire buffer to the file.

.

```
result_t buffer[MAXLEN];

#pragma omp prarellel for
for (size_t i=0; i<width; i++) {
    for (size_t j=0; j<imin(i, width-i+1); j++) {
        result_t result = do_calculation(i, j);
        size_t k=.....;
        buffer[k]=result;
    }
}

fwrite_buffer(f, buffer, total_length);
```

### update

Since your result date is large (~10GB), you may spend most of the time writing data to disk. However multi-thread code usually won't be able to improve the performance for a disk bandwidth bounded task. You should re-consider if multi-thread is good choice for your task.

If buffer size is a problem, you could keep the original design, and use `omp critical` to avoid the race condition on file access.

```
#pragma omp prarellel for schedule(dynamic,3)
for (size_t i=0; i<width; i++) {
result_t buffer[MAXLEN];
    for (size_t j=0; j<imin(i, width-i+1); j++) {
        result_t result = do_calculation(i, j);
        size_t k=ijw2k(i,j,width);
        #pragma omp critical {
            fseek(f, k * bytes_per_result, SEEK_SET);
            fwrite_buffer(f, result);
        }
    }
}
```

According to your code, calculating `k` seems a little bit complex but still doable. `k` is simply a function of `i, j, width`, which should not be a problem for you I suppose.

```
size_t ijw2k(size_t i, size_t j, size_t width) {
    size_t k;
    if (width % 2) {
        if (i<width-i+1) {
            ....
        } else {
            ....
        }
    } else {
        if (i<width-i+1) {
            ....
        } else {
            ....
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

Comment: the combined results are ~10GB, so nope :) also finding out the correct term where you just put `.....` would already solve my problem.

Comment: @flyingsheep large size of disk access should be considered in parallel program design. I've updated my answer.

Comment: No, I don't spend much time writing to disk. The calculation takes enough time that IO is negligible. But I think I'll go with calculating k from the loop variables. It's less elegant than simply incrementing, but it's worth it for the speed